# Android Firebase App Indexing Personal Content not working on tablet

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I have implemented Android Firebase App Indexing Personal Content in my app. I am indexing articles for easy search from Google Search Assistant. It works fine with Phones[tested on Samsung S7 Edge & S8] but does not show up the results in any tablets [Nexus 7(5.0.1), Samsung Tab S2(7.0)].

Also the entries are listed in Settings -> Google Settings -> FireBase App Indexing, under the application. in correct way in both Phones & Tablets.

```
url: "android-app//custom-package/....."
type: "DigitalDocument"
nane: ["FC Barcelona..."]
metadata:{
   worksoffline:false
   score:0
}
```

Screenshots:-

Search Works with Phones:

[image: Search Works with Phones]

Search Result not working in Tablet:

[image: Search Result not working in Tablet]

Below is the code where I am storing articles as personal content in System.

```
 ArrayList<Indexable> indexableArticles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (IndexEntry e : indexFeed) {
        Indexable articleToIndex = Indexables.digitalDocumentBuilder()
                .setName(e.getTitle())
                .setUrl(e.getUrl())
                .build();

        indexableArticles.add(articleToIndex);
    }

    if (indexableArticles.size() > 0) {
        Indexable[] indexedArr = new Indexable[indexableArticles.size()];
        indexedArr = indexableArticles.toArray(indexedArr);

        // batch insert indexable articles into index
        FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(indexedArr);
    }
```

Also I am using 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.6' library

Can't figure out what is the issue in Tablet even after it indexes the articles. Happy to recieve you'll help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check/include the version of the Google Search app on both devices?

Comment: I had reported the same with firebase team as major bug, and they acknowledge that is a bug in tablet and they will fix this issue in coming releases. Hoping it happens soon..

Comment: This is the reply I got from the one of the firebase support executive. 

_I got an update from the team, as of now, Personal Content Indexing is not supported in Tablets but we're actively looking into this. I can't share any details or timelines at this time.

Keep an eye out on our release notes for any further updates._